# Categories lock up and will not accept additional products

Tags: category

This is an ongoing problem. I am adding new products to a category using the Admin Panel and suddenly it stops updating with the new products. It has happened with as few as 6 products in the category and as many as 600.
My only solution has been to delete the category and rebuild it.

Any thoughts would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Your Database may be struggling to keep up.

Try to turn off reindexing after save, and set that to manual reindex.
System->Index Management - Actions ( drop down ) and use Change Index Mode.  Once you do that a new drop down appears: Index Mode, change that to Manual.
[image]

Turning off the reindexing while you create products will means the products will not show up on the front end right away, but that may be better than what your experiencing.

Running the indexes from the command line when your ready is a good option.
SSH into your server and cd into the proper directory that has your magento code and run this command:

```
php shell/indexer.php --reindexall
```